# Google Sheets - Auto Increment numbers based on a cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently trying to make number increment based on a cell value
For example, if the cell value is 5, then a number increment should appear shows in row by row as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Anyone has ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `SEQUENCE()` function. Try-

```
=SEQUENCE(B1)
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en)